# Need assistance with understanding the use of many recovery partitions

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-7-restore

I am on a Dell Inspiron 15R 5537 machine that had Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 dual booted. *The hard drive malfunctioned and I had to get it replaced.*
I thankfully had a system image backup created (using Windows 7 Backup and Recovery within Windows 10), which I used to restore my EFI, Windows installation, and recovery partitions.

*The system image recovery process had ended with an error:*

> Error 0x80070057 - “The Parameter is Incorrect”

However, I booted up and saw that the recovery appeared to have completed successfully, at least for the EFI and Windows(C:) partitions. My PC is working normally, however, **I am not sure if the oem recovery partition was successfully restored.** Is there any way to check whether the recovery partitions are sound?

Further, I currently see ***a lot of recovery partitions.* (490MB, 450MB, 450MB, 350MB, 12.35GB)**. 
(These were most probably present before in my last hard drive, before it failed, too. Not sure of it.)

[image: Windows Disk Management after system image recovery]

In the image above, the three unlabeled *Primary* partitions correspond to my earlier Ubuntu installation (which of course was not recovered but the system image recovery created the respective drives for root, swap and home, nonetheless).

Is there a way for me to understand **which of these recovery partitions are still useful and which are not** (so I can deallocate them to get some more space)?

Thank you.

Comment: Why exactly do you want the OEM recovery partition?  The OEM recovery partition if used results in Windows being reinstalled.  That can be done with a Windows ISO and is probably better because you don't get the fluffware from the OEM

Comment: The first three partitions are the only partitions you must have besides the system partition